# display flex doesn't work on summary tags in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have a `display: flex` on a `<summary>` tag with some child `<p>` elements. It should arrange them in a row, right? and it does, but only in Firefox. Not on Chrome (43.0.2357.81). Is it just me?

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/laggingreflex/5e83uqf9/

```css
summary {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
summary h3 {
  display: block;
  flex: 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<summary>
  <h3>Heading</h3>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
</summary>
```

Comment: only commenting to let you know that it is not just you, i see it too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`summary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) element is not a structural tag, it has its own display properties. It is meant to be a toggled visibility box for the `details` tag.

According to both the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary#Browser_compatibility) and [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=details), Chrome has fully implemented the `summary` tag, while Firefox has not. For an un-implemented tag type, the default behavior of most major browsers is to draw the element as a generic block-level element. In Firefox, then, using the `summary` tag is essentially the same as using the `div` tag. In Chrome; however, it may very well be rendered as a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element), which would mean (among other things) that you cannot override its display type.

EDIT: The `summary` tag is now implemented in Firefox as well, as of version 49.